# How to paint individual RGB components of an image on the j frame

Tags: java, image, swing, awt

I need to print the output of this program(i.e the three images) on Jframe ... the code is below ...I can store it in "test" folder of netbeans but just cant display it..

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class RGBSpliter {
   static BufferedImage image;
   static BufferedImage redImage, greenImage, blueImage;
   static final int TYPE = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      image = ImageIO.read(new File("F:\\Images\\animated\\008.jpg"));
      int w = image.getWidth();
      int h = image.getHeight();
      redImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      greenImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      blueImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
         for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha_mask = pixel & 0xff000000;
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
            redImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | (red << 16));
            greenImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | (green << 8));
            blueImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | blue);
         }
      String format = "png";
      ImageIO.write(redImage, format, new File("image_red.png"));
      ImageIO.write(greenImage, format, new File("image_green.png"));
      ImageIO.write(blueImage, format, new File("image_blue.png"));
   }
}
```

Comment: `frame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(redImage)))` ... ?

Comment: Isn't all the bit-shifting rather more complicated than it needs to be?  Could be `redImage.setRGB(x,y,pixel & 0xffff0000); greenImage.setRGB(x,y,pixel & 0xff00ff00); blueImage.setRGB(x,y,pixel & 0xff0000ff);`

Comment: @MadProgrammer_ we have tried your code. But it didnt work. The image is not getting displayed in the jFrame.Please, I need your help urgently.

Comment: @DavidWallace- We need to separate RGB planes of an image. Like the whole image should be displayed as the red,blue and green components of the image. Most importantly it should be done on a jFrame.

Comment: You will want to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to best help us understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me:

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class RGBSpliter {
   static BufferedImage image;
   static BufferedImage redImage, greenImage, blueImage;
   static final int TYPE = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      String imgPath =
           "https://duke.kenai.com/china/.Midsize/DragonGoldenMedium.jpg.png";
      URL imgUrl = new URL(imgPath);
      image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);


      int w = image.getWidth();
      int h = image.getHeight();
      redImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      greenImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      blueImage = new BufferedImage(w, h, TYPE);
      for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
         for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            int pixel = image.getRGB(x, y);
            int alpha_mask = pixel & 0xff000000;
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel) & 0xff;
            redImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | (red << 16));
            greenImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | (green << 8));
            blueImage.setRGB(x, y, alpha_mask | blue);
         }
      }
      // String format = "png";

      Image[] images = {image, redImage, greenImage, blueImage};
      for (Image localImage : images) {
         ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(localImage);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: __ can't we print them on JFrame at desired location such as this    JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("RGB");
        f.setSize(new Dimension(1360,760));
        f.setVisible(true);

Comment: @user3335751: you can display them on the JFrame the same as you would any other image: as ImageIcons in a JLabel or as images painted in a JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method.

Comment: done ..used the paint component and got the desired output...thanks for help